# Not able to run Red5

Tags: red5, bigbluebutton

I was following the instructions mentioned in below link to install  'Bigbluebutton'

http://bigbluebutton.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3300/wiki/InstallingBigBlueButtonCentOS.wiki

After the installation of Red5 I started the service successfully with

```
service red5 start
```

But I am not able to access http://:5080/ from the server or from other machines to continue with the installation. Running 'netstat -tulpn' does not even list port 5080. Red5 properties file is configured with port 5080 only.

Any idea what would be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the product manager for BigBlueButton.  Your trying to install on CentOS, and we've not supported the CentOS packaging for many years.

See our FAQ for more details

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/support/faq.html#centos